# Converting array of objects to newline string

Tags: javascript

I am using following line of code to split an array of objects to comma separated values

```
var myArray = [{Name: "apple"}, {Name: "Banana "}];
type : { DisplayText: myArray.length > 0 ? myArray.map(function (elm) { return elm.Name }).join(", ") : null,
         property1: 'a',
         Property2: 'b'
       }
```

**Output:**

```
apple, Banana
```

However, how i can generate the following output

```
apple
Banana
```

**Note:**
The following `does not work`. It generates output `apple Banana`

```
DisplayText: myArray.length > 0 ? myArray.map(function (elm) { return elm.Name }).join("\n") : null,
```

**Update:**
Actually i am creating `type object` with `DisplayText` property and `two other properties`. That's why i have `,` at the end of line . Have a look at my updated answer

Comment: .join("\n") does that

Comment: No, that generates out apple Banana

Comment: yes i updated my question, my array is exactly in the format you said, it was just type while posting this question.I repeat my array is array of objects with Name property in each object

Comment: @JapanGuy, As i said before "\n" does not work at all. Dont understand why people upvoted your answer even though i clearly said It does not work

Comment: @simbada—post your code as a runnable snippet showing it to "not work". If you want minimal code,  `myArray.map(x => x.Name).join('\n') || null` works for me.

Comment: because it works on my compiler

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j71cts6s/

Comment: still works with your new code https://jsfiddle.net/3y8jqged/

Comment: Thanks you are right. let me see on my side

Comment: Since i was rendering this out to ui-grid and i suspect its default celltemplate that does not allow line break. I have to look around to fix that. thansk guys

Answer (score 2):

Its working remove the `,` with end of the displaytext `null;` instead of `null,`

```js
var myArray = [{Name: "apple"}, {Name: "Banana "}];
var type = { DisplayText: myArray.length > 0 ? myArray.map(function (elm) { return elm.Name }).join("\n ") : null,
         property1: 'a',
         Property2: 'b'
       }
  console.log(type.DisplayText)
```

**Using html try with `join('<br>')`**

```js
var myArray = [{Name: "apple"}, {Name: "Banana "}];
var type = { DisplayText: myArray.length > 0 ? myArray.map(function (elm) { return elm.Name }).join("<br> ") : null,
         property1: 'a',
         Property2: 'b'
       }
document.body.innerHTML +=type.DisplayText
```

Comment: please have a look at my updated question. There is a reason i was putting , at the end of line

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
   var myArray = ["apple", "Banana "];
DisplayText: myArray.length > 0 ? myArray.map(function (elm) { return elm.Name }).join("\n") : null,
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [array#join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method with `,` as separator

```js
var myArray = ["apple", "Banana "];
console.log(myArray.join(','));
```

It will take `,` as default separator if no symbol is passed

```js
var myArray = ["apple", "Banana "];
    console.log(myArray.join());
```

Edit(after question update)

```js
var arr = [{
  Name: "apple"
}, {
  Name: "Banana "
}];
var newStr = '';

var x = arr.map(function(item) {
  newStr = item.Name;
  return newStr;

}).join();

console.log(x)
```

Comment: Please check my updated question. My array is an array of objects and not array of strings. e.g. var myArray = [{Name: "apple"}, {Name: "Banana "}];

Comment: `.join(',')` and `.join()` are functionally identical since the default join character is ",".